# How do I bind a PyQt4 Signal to a slot of another object?

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am working on making a digital signage raspberry pi.   I need to make a simple slide show using pyqt4.

I want to bind a signal to a slot that is a function from a different class.  Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
import glob

class Signals(QObject):
 trigger = pyqtSignal(object)
 def connect(self):
    self.trigger.connect(self.alter)
 def alter(self,func):
    func.advance()
 def e(self,f):
    self.trigger.emit(f)


class Slide:
 def __init__(self):
    self.position = 0
    self.slidelst = glob.glob('bkgrnd*.jpg')
 def populate(self):
    self.slidelst = glob.glob('bkgrnd*.jpg')
 def advance(self):
    if self.position == len(self.slidelst)-1:
        self.position = 0
    else:
        self.position+=1
        print("signal")
 def current(self):
    return self.slidelst[self.position]
```

This code does not run correctly, instead saying that the instance of my object 'Slide' has no attribute 'advance'.   I have also tried reworking it so that the connection is connected directly to the advance method of the slide class... but i have been unable to get that to run without a typeerror (Python wants a function type instead of a NoneType).

Please help me!  Sorry for the basic question, it has been a long time since my last computer science class...

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Questions asking for debugging help without such an example (the example needs to be runnable!) are likely to be closed as off-topic until you provide one.

Comment: To make it clear what is missing, you don't show how you call `Signals.e`, or what you pass in as the value for `f` which affects the whole signal emission process.

Comment: A signal that emits a function seems pretty redundant - why not just connect directly to the function itself? All you need to do is: `sig = Signals(); slide = Slide(); sig.trigger.connect(slide.advance)`. Then again, the `Signals` class also seems redundant. It should really be something like a button or menu item in the GUI that emits the signal.